# Update the cell value in Observablehq reactive environment

Tags: javascript, reactive, observablehq

When code in the cell tries to update the value of another cell Observablehq Runtime can't see this event.

The simple example on Observablehq: https://beta.observablehq.com/@sen77/updating-a-cell-from-another-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing, here's a solution that uses [mutable state](https://beta.observablehq.com/@jashkenas/introduction-to-mutable-state):

https://beta.observablehq.com/d/e57c4f7c734d7b39

Observable aims to be a functional-programming flavored reactive environment, so *mutable* values like this one aren't handled automatically: methods like `[].push()` are not easily tracked.